# Retrieving firebase children and populating them in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

> Trying to query firebase children and retrieve a snapshot array of their data into a tableview. Not sure if I am implementing this correctly, but I am not the getting a runtime error. However, my tableview is just white with no objects displaying. Some feedback would be helpful. Thanks.

Here is my FB JSON tree structure

> [image: Here is my FB JSON tree structure.]

Here is my User class (var userList = User)

> [image: Here is my User class (var userList = [User]())]

```
class CDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    static var imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, UIImage>()

    var userList = [User]()

    var ref = FIREBASE.FBDataReference().ref

    var refHandle: UInt!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = FIREBASE.FBLink().FBref
        configureCell()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows


        return userList.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CDetailTableViewCell



        cell.priceLabel?.text = userList[indexPath.row].priceLabel
        cell.titleLabel?.text = userList[indexPath.row].titleLabel
        cell.itemPhoto?.image = userList[indexPath.row].objectImage

        return cell


    }


    func configureCell(){

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        refHandle = ref.child("Enterpriser Listings").child("Sell Old Stuff - Listings").child(userID!).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]  {

                print("get dictionary")
                print(dictionary)

                let user = User()

                user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                self.userList.append(user)

                // Get user value

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    print("reloaded")

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }


            }
        })

    }


    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: did you try breakpoints? you have "print" so did you look in your console?

Comment: @Lu_ yeah, no print statements were executed in the console

Comment: @KyleC.Beachem You want all the records from Firebase not the single one that you are showing in image.

Comment: @NiravD yes I do want all records, but at the moment in that image is the only record I have for that class

Comment: @KyleC.Beachem Can you add the console log for `print(snapshot.children)`  add this print statement below the line `if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]  {` and respond here what is log for it.

Comment: @NiravD no log was printed in the console even with a breakpoint. I don't think that part of code is being executed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the problem is with your `Firebase` reference, try like this way.

```
ref.child("Enterpriser Listings").child("Sell Old Stuff - Listings").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in
    var users = [User]()
    for child in snapshot.children {
        print("\((sweet as! FIRDataSnapshot).value)")
        if let dictionary = child.value as? [String : AnyObject]  {
            let user = User()
            user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            users.append(user)
        } 
    }
    self.userList = users
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: @KyleC.Beachem Check the edited answer and where you are getting this crash?

Comment: @KyleC.Beachem This crash is may be coming from the class User and method `setValuesForKeys`.Put break point in method and check where it is crashing.

Comment: yeah getting nil values for that class here [link](http://gdurl.com/hJx7)

Comment: @KyleC.Beachem You need to put the break point inside that `setValuesForKeys` method and check where it is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Simple question. Have you delegated your tableview?

```
class YourController: < other >, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() { //for example this function
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: yeah, look at the edit. I am using a UITableViewController.